# Откуда знают что "глубь" произошло от "глубокий" а не наоборот?

Tags: словообразование

Мой учебник говорит что слово *глубь* образовано безаффиксным способом от прилагательного *глубокий*. Откуда они знают что произошло не наоборот? Что сначала было существительное *глубь*, а потом появилось прилагательное *глубокий*. Нужно ли залезать глубоко в историю русского языка, чтобы доказать это, или есть более общие и простые правила?

Comment: статистика словоупотребления, как ещё?

Comment: Не уверен, что на статистику употребления можно опираться в этом случае, Бостона очень сильно зависит от быта, в частности, того времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> для того чтобы установить производность слова и, следовательно, определить, какое из сравниваемых родственных слов послужило базой для образования другого, то есть какое имеет производящую основу, а какое — производную, надо изучить конкретную историю этих слов и выяснить, какое из них более раннее, а какое более позднее, какое из слов исторически образовано от другого

[Словообразование синхронное и историческое](http://sci-book.com/russkiy-yazyik/slovoobrazovanie-sinhronnoe-istoricheskoe-72110.html) (В. А. Белошапкова, Е. А. Брызгунова, Е. А. Земская и др.. Современный русский язык: Учеб. для филол. спец. ун-тов)

Comment: This sounds like begging the question to me.

Comment: @Quassnoi Yep, the last clause is too much.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, [источники](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8C) утверждают, что слова `глубь` и `глубина` произошли от слова глубокий. Данное слово пришло из праславянского языка и, видимо, сначала сразу закрепилось, как прилагательное, а затем далее было образовано существительное. Узнать это можно поиском по этимологии слова. Попытки понять чисто через механизмы словообразования не всегда дают верное представление, так как образование конкретных слов зачастую действительно уходит корнями в историю.

Answer (score 2):

[Николай Данилович Голев](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), у которого мне посчастливилось учиться, советовал придерживаться синхронного подхода к словообразованию и говорил, что нужно смотреть, какое из двух слов сложнее - семантически и формально. Семантически, глубь - это глубокое место. Значит, семантически, "глубь" = "глубокий" + "место". Следовательно, "глубокий" - базовое слово, "глубь" образовалось от него.

Формальную словообразовательную цепочку я бы построила так: глубокий + суффикс существительного -ин + флексия = глубина. Глубина - обратный суффиксальный способ словообразования = глубь. Возможно, моя цепочка неверна, я лишь предполагаю, что это так.

Comment: А если наоборот. Что такое *глубокий*? Это то, у чего есть *глубь*. А *глубь* ничем не определяется, нужно заранее знать что это такое, так же как слово *хлеб*.

Comment: @Graduate базовое слово скорее всего "*глубъ" в значение расщелина, если верить Фасмеру. (Сюда же приглу́бой «глубокий», арханг., колымск. Вероятно, снабженный носовым инфиксом к. греч. γλύφω «выдалбливаю», лат. glūbō «лущу», др.-в.-нем. klioban, др.-исл. kliúfa «расщепляю, раскалываю», др.-в.-нем. klūbōn «раскалывать», kluft «расселина, пропасть».) Вообще все эти слова:  высокий, глубокий, далекий -- очень темные, и во всех славянских языках они существуют без оригинала.